# How to get Site Collection name(or type)?

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, site-template, spsite

I`m making a windows application that analyse the SharePoint site.

In SPSite Level, I want to get Site Collection name.

Which means, I already got Site template name like this STS.

```
private string GetSiteTemplateName(SPSite site)
{
    string retValue = string.Empty;
    string webAppUrl = site.Url;

    using (SPSite sites = new SPSite(webAppUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = sites.OpenWeb())
        {
            retValue = web.WebTemplate;
        }
    }

    return retValue;
}
```

But for end users, they don`t know about STS, So I try to change that lite this : Team Site

I try to find that, but I`m not sure how can I do that.

Does anybody know about this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SPSite.RootWeb.Title` to get web title....

in your case it would be `web.Title`. I would have used below to get Title/Name of Site collection.

```
private string GetSiteTitle(SPSite site)
{
    return site.RootWeb.Title
}
```